# Formula which subtracts a cell value from a total based on the date

Tags: excel, date, formula

I am trying to create a budget sheet with a formula that essentially deducts an amount due from the total outstanding based on today's date and the dates each amount is due. So what I am trying to achieve is, for example, in the image link below. So for example, if I access the sheet on the 10th May, I would see the total amount due less the amounts due on 1st and 8th May as these dates have passed

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to include current date (i.e. the same date as today) as outstanding then use following formula:

`=SUMIF(A2:A5,">="&TODAY(),B2:B5)`

If you do not want to include then drop equal to symbol

`=SUMIF(A2:A5,">"&TODAY(),B2:B5)`